# Is there a way to check if an ASIN has been merged via the Amazon MWS API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws, amazon-marketplace

I'm wondering if there is a way to verify if an ASIN has been merged with another via an API call. I have a few products where I created a listed and matched it with an existing ASIN. A few weeks later that ASIN was merged with another ASIN. Amazon sends and email when an ASIN is Merged with another ASIN but I would like to be able to check if an ASIN used in a listing is valid and if not see the ASIN it was merged with so I can update my listing. When I query for CompetitivePrice / LowestPrice / MyPrice using the ASIN I have stored in my listing, which is no longer valid, I do not get any results back for that ASIN.

Here is an example ASIN:

B00MOHMZO6
[http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00MOHMZO6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00MOHMZO6)

It was merged with B00MBUO68E
[http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00MBUO68E](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00MBUO68E)

Clicking on either URL takes you to the same page.

Just a bit of additional info. When I try and pull CompetitivePricing for an ASIN that has been merged I get the following response which lets me know it is not valid. If the reason the ASIN is not valid because it was merged with another ASIN it would be nice to know which ASIN it was merged with.

```
    <GetCompetitivePricingForASINResult ASIN="B00MOHMZO6" status="ClientError">
        <Error>
            <Type>Sender</Type>
            <Code>InvalidParameterValue</Code>
            <Message>ASIN B00MOHMZO6 is not valid for marketplace ATVPDKIKX0DER</Message>
        </Error>
    </GetCompetitivePricingForASINResult>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Only way to find the merged ASINs is to use Amazon MWS Product's API call "GetMyPriceForSKURequest" and you will get these XML response

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<GetMyPriceForSKUResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01">
  <GetMyPriceForSKUResult SellerSKU="mks-plw-sft-sil-eplgs-valpk-6-x1a" status="Success">
    <Product>
      <Identifiers>
        <MarketplaceASIN>
          <MarketplaceId>A1F83G8C2ARO7P</MarketplaceId>
          <ASIN>B000TC2XLS</ASIN>
        </MarketplaceASIN>
        <SKUIdentifier>
          <MarketplaceId>A1F83G8C2ARO7P</MarketplaceId>
          <SellerId>AAAAAAAAAAAAAA</SellerId>
          <SellerSKU>mks-plw-sft-sil-eplgs-valpk-6-x1a</SellerSKU>
        </SKUIdentifier>
      </Identifiers>
      <Offers>
        <Offer>
          <BuyingPrice>
            <LandedPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>4.73</Amount>
            </LandedPrice>
            <ListingPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>4.73</Amount>
            </ListingPrice>
            <Shipping>
              <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>0.00</Amount>
            </Shipping>
          </BuyingPrice>
          <RegularPrice>
            <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>4.73</Amount>
          </RegularPrice>
          <FulfillmentChannel>MERCHANT</FulfillmentChannel>
          <ItemCondition>New</ItemCondition>
          <ItemSubCondition>New</ItemSubCondition>
          <SellerId>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</SellerId>
          <SellerSKU>mks-plw-sft-sil-eplgs-valpk-6-x1a</SellerSKU>
        </Offer>
        <Offer>
          <BuyingPrice>
            <LandedPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>5.13</Amount>
            </LandedPrice>
            <ListingPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>5.13</Amount>
            </ListingPrice>
            <Shipping>
              <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>0.00</Amount>
            </Shipping>
          </BuyingPrice>
          <RegularPrice>
            <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>5.13</Amount>
          </RegularPrice>
          <FulfillmentChannel>AMAZON</FulfillmentChannel>
          <ItemCondition>New</ItemCondition>
          <ItemSubCondition>New</ItemSubCondition>
          <SellerId>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</SellerId>
          <SellerSKU>fba-mks-plw-sft-sil-eplgs-valpk-6-x1a</SellerSKU>
        </Offer>
      </Offers>
    </Product>
  </GetMyPriceForSKUResult>
  <ResponseMetadata>
    <RequestId>6a6044a3-5cdd-4600-b310-02233924bc64</RequestId>
  </ResponseMetadata>
</GetMyPriceForSKUResponse>
```

And you can get ASIN from Product->Identifiers->MarketplaceASIN->ASIN XML element which is always the latest ASIN on amazon, Which you can check against your ASIN if they are same.